# How to create a custom stylesheet notebook?

Tags: stylesheet, customization

I want to be able to define and change all my notebook's styles globally.  I therefore want to create a new stylesheet notebook.  It seems like something that should be easy to do for simple modifications from the default stylesheet.  But I have not found anything telling me how to do it.

How can I create my own stylesheet notebook, and use it for all the notbooks in my project?

Will changes to that stylesheet show up in my notebooks after I have already chosen it for that notebook?

I am not asking how to modify the private style sheet of a notebook.

Comment: Check out this [new doc page](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/29974), let me know if it doesn't answer your question.  One thing though, is that it won't apply by default to notebooks you've already saved.  I don't know how to do that easily without some kind of commandline script, which seems dangerous.

Comment: Yup, the above link covers the most of it. In short, create a stylesheet with your modified styles, and save and apply it using the information in the article. Further notebooks you'd have to manually specify that they refer to the new one I think, which is unfortunate, but not too hard. There's probably a quip of code you could use to do it.

Comment: Jason B.  That did, collaterally, provide the answer I was looking for, and more.  The part I wasn't getting was that saving the private stylesheet from the "Private Style Definitions for ..." window would save the private stylesheet as a notebook.  One point of confusion was that the file save dialog was populating the file name field with the notebook owning the stylesheet.